# Как отправить эмодзи через Telegram API по коду эмодзи?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Можно ли отправить эмодзи через Telegram API по его коду?

Например, при вводе `:ru:` в чате преобразуется во флаг России. Хочу также отправлять флаги в виде эмодзи по коду страны, чтоб не заморачиваться и не сохранять все флаги к каждой стране вручную в байтах. Реально ли это сделать? В официальной документации ничего не нашел(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте отправить юникод символ желаемого emoji.

Например, в Python используется библиотека [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/). Под капотом перевод указанного вами ствольного варианта (`:ua:`) в юникод символ. [Про юникод символы](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), [alias'ы через двоеточия](https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/)